# Error in restoring Tensorflow faster RCNN model from checkpoint file due to absence of ROI pooling layer

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I need to restore a Faster RCNN model in a project. But I am not able to do as there is no ROI pooling layer in Tensorflow.

How can I include a customized ROI pooling layer? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Do you have an error message and stack trace?

Comment: Got error like No Roi Pooling Layer in tensorflow.....I tried to install this tensorflow https://github.com/zplizzi/tensorflow-fast-rcnn  but am getting some errors in installation...I got this error while installation https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4944

Answer (score 0):

We use [crop and resize](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py#L1087) for ROI.